# How to fix pyautogui pixel error on scaled Retina display?

Tags: python, macos, retina-display, pyautogui

I want to push a specific button.

I am using pyautogui. I am using Macbook Pro 15 inch(2012).

My scaling is set to 1680 * 1050 (default scaling is 1440 * 900).

Many people seem to have the same problem especially Retina mac users and virtual desktop users.

But since retina mac users are using with **default scaling**, which is, in case of 15 inch, 1440 * 900.

## getting position

```
import pyautogui as auto
import time

time.sleep(3)
button = auto.position()
print(button)
```

returns
`Point(x=1679, y=1049)`

## trying to adjust the scaling

https://medium.com/@tracy_blog/pyautogui-and-retina-displays-2d5c37a5aa5e
Referring to this post, I tried to fix the problem. Note that 1.7142 ≒ 1680 / 2880.

```
    button = auto.locateCenterOnScreen('/Users/username/Programming/right_button.png')
        x = button[0] / 1.7142
        y = button[1] / 1.7142
```

I expect that by adjusting the scaling, I can clink on the button, but I still cannot. Can anybody give me some ideas?

Comment: locateCenterOnScreen() takes a screenshot which is taken with double resolution with respect to the one you get from position(). Then, your button is matched. Therefore, your button must also be in full retina (double) resolution. You then have to divide the coordinates again by a factor of 2, not sqrt(2).